Structuring BLoCs for Multiple API Calls in Flutter
I’m working on a Flutter application using the flutter_bloc package for state management. I have a page that requires fetching data from multiple API endpoints.
Scenario:
The page displays data from different sources, each requiring a separate API call.
I’m considering whether to use a single BLoC to manage all these API calls or to create separate BLoCs for each API call.
Questions:
Single BLoC Approach:
How can I effectively manage multiple asynchronous operations within a single BLoC?
What are the best practices for combining different API responses into a unified state?
Multiple BLoCs Approach:
How can I coordinate state and handle errors across multiple BLoCs?
What strategies can I use to aggregate data from multiple BLoCs on the same page?
Current Approach:
I have used the copyWith method to update the state with responses from different API calls, but I’m concerned about the maintainability of this approach.
Additional Context:
I want to ensure that my approach is scalable and maintainable.
Any insights, examples, or patterns from your experience would be greatly appreciated!
I initially tried using a single BLoC to handle all the API calls for the page. I implemented the copyWith method to update the state with responses from different APIs. My expectation was that this approach would consolidate all the data into a unified state and make state management simpler.
However, I encountered issues with maintaining readability and scalability. The state management code became complex as I tried to handle different responses and potential errors. Combining multiple API responses into a single state with copyWith proved challenging, and I was concerned about the maintainability of this approach as the page's complexity grew.
I also considered creating separate BLoCs for each API call to isolate concerns and manage each response individually. My expectation was that this would make the code more modular and easier to debug. However, I struggled with how to coordinate and aggregate the data from these multiple BLoCs on the same page.
I am looking for guidance on how to efficiently manage multiple asynchronous operations, maintain clean and readable code, and combine different API responses effectively.

You can use MultiBlocProvider for declaring the Bloc and MultiBlocListener for getting the data from API and display it inside BlocBuilder

could you provide some page structure with some complexity level where you faced concern with maintainability?

The best answer I have seen is from this article, linkhttps://medium.com/@hmtamim/composite-bloc-in-flutter-streamlining-complex-screens-with-multi-bloc-b5d5fbfa3aba. He explains it from cradle to the point where you can make the decision yourself on whether to use Presentation layer or Domain layer.
